# Extending an AVMutableComposition

Tags: ios, avfoundation

I would like to render some graphics to the end of my AVMutableComposition, like credits at the end of a movie. How can I create a blank asset that would extend the composition time to give me some blank space I can render to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer. It lies in the insertEmptyTimeRange method. An example:

```
//comp is an AVMutableComposition

float secondsToExtend = 5.0f;
long long timescale = comp.duration.timescale;
CMTime endTime = CMTimeMake(comp.duration.value - 1, timescale);
CMTime extendDuration = CMTimeMake(secondsToExtend * timescale, timescale);
CMTimeRange emptyTimeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(endTime, extendDuration);
[comp insertEmptyTimeRange:emptyTimeRange];
```

Comment: it doesn't work for me. Space doesn't inserting. i'm trying to add space after the video

Comment: I'm having the same trouble. This works if there is an occupied time range following the empty one, but if the empty time range is at the end the composition seems to ignore it.

Comment: I am trying to insert an empty space at the end and at the start. Although the above code did not help to add blank space at the end, in my case.